# Best word for skill measurement

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'm wondering if it is true to use "estimation" for determining someones's skill. I mean, if someone says I'm a good designer, which word is best to use for a process to measure if he/she is really a good designer?

Skill estimation/evaluation? Or something else?

Comment: Sounds like *Skills assessment* or *Skills evaluation* to me.

Comment: I think `assessment` is a little economical.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *economical*. (It can mean cheap.) But it's common for employers to *assess* or *appraise* their employees.

Comment: What would such a process look like? “Evaluation” seems like a good choice.

Comment: It depends who's doing the estimate: whether it's done in the work environment or somewhere else etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are a few words that can be used in this context. A few that jump to mind are appraisal, assessment and evaluation.

Another related phrase you may see is "Competency Assessment", which is used quite a lot in Industrial and Construction publications to mean, essentially, the process of assuring that any given employee has the appropriate skills, knowledge and qualifications to do a particular task.

However someone who is "competent" at a task does not necessarily need to be highly skilled at that task, so if you are talking about skills in a higher-performance context, you would probably use either skill or ability to describe what you are measuring.